# Would User B be able to register a subdomain on User's A domain with this setup?

Tags: ubuntu

I am making a web hosting service, and I ran into a problem. I am not sure if my thinking is correct and if I should worry at all, but I plan that my users add an A Record pointing to my dedicated server's IP Address. With this approach, I was wondering if it would be possible for User B to "steal" User's A subdomain. For example, User A points example.com to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and User B somehow finds out that User A owns example.com. User A has both example.com and *.example.com pointing to my IP Address. Would User B be able to register test.example.com ? Why or why not?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has nothing to do with Unix or Linux

Comment: "Register" where? If user A points their domain name and points a wildcard A record at your server... then User B registers a subdomain of that **in your software** then your software would host that subdomain for User B and the DNS setup by user A would facilitate browsers reaching it.  Yes you need to know a user owns a subdomain first or you should warn your users not to use wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot register subdomains, only domains off tld's, although there may be multiple levels of domains.

For instance you can register `example.com` but not `l1.example.com`.

You can register `example.eu.com` but not `l1.example.eu.com`, due to `eu.com` being controlled by a `domain name registrar`.

In other words, some domains have special properties where sub domains can be registered.

Clear as mud really...

Comment: Yes, but that would violate the op's question, since the owner can stop another buying a subdomain.

Comment: Yeah I was really just pointing out that this sentence is misleading: `In other words, some domains have special properties where sub domains can be registered.` since there's no "special property".  It would be more accurately worded as *"subdomains are not for sale"*

Answer (score 0):

"Register" where?

If user A points their domain name and points a wildcard A or AAAA record at your server... then User B registers a subdomain of that **in your software** then there might be a problem.

Your software would host that subdomain for User B and the DNS setup by user A would facilitate browsers reaching it.

Yes you need to either ask users to prove ownership or perhaps warn your users not to use wildcard records.